# Loading Images with PIL in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I know that this question has been asked many times, but I still haven't seemed to got an answer from any of the other posts. I am just trying to load an image from my desktop using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
pic = Image.open("/Users/23athreyad/Desktop/turkishflag.jpg")
pic.show()
```

And I always seem to get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/23athreyad/Desktop/turkishflag.jpg'
(base)
```

I have specified the complete path of the file and don't know why it still can't find the image.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Do you mean the os of my mac?

Comment: it is 10.13.3 Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: Can you post the result of the following command: ls -l /Users/23athreyad/Desktop/tur*

Comment: drag/dropping the file from finder can give you the complete path.  using this can help to prevent typos

Comment: @SamMason Thank you, this worked!

Comment: @AthreyaDaniel I'd suggest marking MeghdeepRay's answer as accepted, it was the underlying cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are providing the wrong absolute path for the file you want to open. It cannot be found at that location. The code you are using is correct and accurate to the [official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/handbook/tutorial.html#using-the-image-class).

Comment: this problem isn't specific to PIL, any time you interact with the file system you need to make sure you're referring to the correct file name/path